# Archivo CSV como argumento en Ansible

Tags: csv, ansible

Estoy intentando desarrollar un script ansible para automatizar tareas en mi empresa. Una de nuestras necesidades es pasar a ansible tower un archivo csv como argumento. Luego leeríamos su contenido para nuestras necesidades.

¿Alguien sabe si esto es posible? Supongo que no es posible... pero sólo busco la confirmación de los expertos.

Gracias.

Comment: Hello, we are in Stack Overflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) En español, por favor. 2) Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.